# Java File.delete() hangs or taking too long

Tags: java

I'm simply deleting a file based on a filter

```
public void delete(String folder, String filter){
   File f = new File(path);
   String[] files = f.list();
   for (string s : files){
      if (s.indexOf(filter) >= 0){
          new File(folder + s).delete(); 
      }
   }
}
```

This usually goes well in a few microseconds.

On occasion though, I have users report this section hangs. If the app becomes unresponsive for too long, I kill it and grab the stacktrace, and this is where the thread is at:

at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.delete

This also happens when writing to a file sometimes. I'm wondering if it can the file being locked by the JVM. Any way of checking for this?

Comment: This is most likely a windows issue. The file may be locked or similar.

Comment: Are you trying to delete files on a remote filesytem? If so, anything can happen, including nothing.

Comment: Files are local on the PC. I'm thinking these files might very well be accessed by other processes while I am manipulating them, perhaps even during the java calls. If a file is being manipulated and another process locks it during, is this expected behaviour?

Comment: Do not use `delete()`. Try to use `Files.delete()`.

Comment: The problem is I'm seeing this in not just File.delete(), but also writing to files. I might try and convert all file manipulation to Files instead, it's a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Something in the OS probably has the file open. Anyone has seen the issue in Windows when a file is open in their IDE or something and they are trying to delete a directory.

Java NIO has some features which may help, FileChannel, FileLock. It's not great.

For example, you could kill it for running long, then check to see if you can get an exclusive lock

```
File file = new File(fileName);
FileChannel channel = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw").getChannel();

FileLock lock = channel.lock();
if(lock.isValid() && !lock.isShared()){
  // lock is exclusive, you should be able to delete if you have permissions
} else {
  // cannot get lock
}
channel.close();
```

Comment: Would it be expected behaviour for the system call from java to hang if a file was indeed locked? Sounds like unbelievable bad design if that's the case.

Comment: @Jake I'm unsure of that. It seems it should be reproduceable locally by opening a file in something like Notepad and trying to delete it through a simple test program.

Comment: I did, but with no success. Opened it in notepad, make some changes without saving. Also tried opening it in eclipse, couldn't reproduce it sadly. Thanks for helping out!

Comment: if you're on windows, maybe you could try navigating into a .zip or .jar file. Windows 10 will allow you to browse into it, but it's not really extracted. Usually I cannot delete (from windows explorer) an archive I'm browsing, a  use case for me is like in my maven target folder when I'm viewing the archive contents.